# best approach for storing formatted text in database

Tags: database

I am writing a java servlet/jsp based webapp, using jdbc to retrieve/store data in the db.

The next iteration will use markdown to allow users to format the text. My question is, what is the best way to have the database ignore the markdown markup in a search? I've done some searching here, and some people have recommended storing the markdown and html in different tables, so it doesn't need to be converted to html every time it's called.

Is it a good idea to take a similar approach with just the raw data? Right now my current plan is to have a display_text table and a search_text table. I supposed I could add a third for html.

Right now the simplicity and functionality is more important than the disk space. But how does stackoverflow handle that?

Comment: Somewhat related to this topic is this:
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/11/se-podcast-28-brent-ozar/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, have 3 fields. The issue will probably be data integrity between the 3 fields, rather than disk space. To avoid that, consider making 2 of the fields 'calculated' fields - if you are using a dbms that supports that.

Answer (score 2):

CPU is cheap, and *bloody* fast. Until you find that it's a bottleneck, I would render on every page view. That's certainly the simplest approach.